# Convert code from a Windows Game Project to XBox Game Project

Tags: c#, game-physics, xbox

I have a PC that i code on and an Xbox that i am juuust starting to test on.  I have made a few programs (even entire games) on my PC under a Windows Game project.  I would like to take that same code and then simply test it in a (probably) new project for an Xbox Game project. My question is thus: how does one convert code from a Windows Game Project to XBox Game Project?

Comment: So, apparently i do not covert code. Rather i can copy a project to an XBOX project and run it that way. I think that doing it this way is rather slow, i may just copy it to a flash drive and run it straight from the 360 instead of from my PC, and over the network.